# Dynamically Selecting by ID

Tags: jquery

I have the ID of a selected textarea stored in a variable. Is it possible to use that variable to select the element by ID later on in the code? For example:

```
var currentTextarea = null;

function foo() {
    currentTextarea = 'pageid'; // This will be set dynamically via an event. Example only.
}

function bar() {
    $('#' + currentTextarea).val(); // Although this don't seem to work
}
```

Comment: Ah. The browser was caching my Javascript so I wasn't seeing results. Thanks for the replies guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, your code should work - be sure to call foo() before bar() otherwise it'be a null value...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that; I've done that before with no problems.  Make sure currentTextarea is defined before it runs... or make sure nothing else is changing the value (since it's a global variable).

Answer (score 0):

It works
http://jsfiddle.net/6hHkC/